# Django - change datetime field output format within values() method

Tags: django

I want to create a list of dict of a queryset where instances have a datetime fields in it. Then, I want to  serialize it and send it in JSON.

I am using this code:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

objectList = Layers.objects.filter(geom_type="Polygon")
values = objectList.values('id', 'name', 'geom_type', 'date_created')
data = list(values)  # becomes list of dictionaries
jsonData = json.dumps(data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
return HttpResponse(jsonData, content_type="application/json")
```

this is working good but I wonder if it's possible to choose the datetime field format to be `yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss` instead of `2014-12-09T16:05:12.132Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this ...

```
data = [[x.id, x.name, x.geom_type, x.date_created.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")] 
        for x in objectList]
```

Or, if you are using the DATETIME_FORMAT setting, you can do

```
data = [[x.id, x.name, x.geom_type, '%s' % x.date_created] 
        for x in objectList]
```

Comment: if you use the second option above and print out one of the elements of `data`, what do you see?

Comment: the output is: 2014-12-09 18:31:46.276000+00:00 with or without the DATETIME_FORMAT = "Y-m-d-h-i-s" in settings

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the quotation marks inside the strftime() the first time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66583/discussion-between-below-the-radar-and-jcfollower).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a DATETIME_FORMAT setting?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/

`DATETIME_FORMAT = "Y-m-d-h-i-s"`

Comment: that was a good suggestion but this setting changes nothing. It seems the DjangoJSONEncoder not affected by this